# Writing and Reading to arrays simultaneously

Tags: c, arrays, embedded

I am currently working on project in which I am using an interrupt to fill an array of 128 values. Each interrupt sequentially updates one value in the array. When the array is full, there will be a short delay, then the process will begin with a batch of new values to fill the array with. The problem comes in that I need to read this array, and I don't want to read it when I am part way through updating the array. 
I have attempted to achieve this in the pseudo-code below, but there is still the problem that the pointers could get swapped halfway through a read.
Does anyone have any ideas on a good way to achieve this?

```
int arrayA[128];
int arrayB[128];

int *readPointer;
int *writePointer;

readPointer = arrayA;
writePointer = arrayB;

void while(1) {
   read();
   delay(100);
}

_interrupt rx() {
   static int index = 0;
   *(writePointer+index) = readVal();
   index++;
   if(index==128) {
      index = 0;
      temp = writePointer;
      writePointer = readPointer;
      readPointer  = temp;
   }
}

void read() {
     int myVal = anyValueInArray;
   }
}
```

Comment: From your question it seemslike you want to read tha array out when it is full...? Why cant you use a simple flag then.. ?

Comment: Off the top of my head: use a doubled buffer and fill half part per time. While interrupt writes the second half you can read the first one and so on. You tagged it as embedded, so you can think to use DMAs with two threshold: half and final.

Comment: Apart from the initial period when there is no full array, after the array has been filled once, the readArray will always be full as the pointer just keeps getting swapped when a new array of data is available. I need to know how it's possible to stop the pointers getting swapped in the middle of a read.

Comment: Actually, I don't see the point of waiting until the array is fully traversed by the interrupt routine. As long as you make sure your read pointer always *stays behind* the write pointer, all is well (just busy-wait in your read routine if you come close to the write pointer). This looks like a classical case of a ring buffer (without the ring). This would also allow you much more time to read and copy data.

Comment: Presumably the read routine can process the inputs faster than they are written to. It's usually not good to have one routine try to interfere with another. You could use two buffers (or a 2-d buffer) and when one is full, you can flag the reading part and swap to the other buffer.

Comment: I think that would be overly cautious. Any keyboard or serial buffer is normally programmed that way and I'd say that's basic tooling in embedded. It's much more dangerous when the read is not done yet and an interrupt comes in - the interrupt routine can't simply busy wait.

Comment: Use a double buffer as already recommended. And, btw., your code will not work with any decent compiler unless you declare your arrays and pointers volatile.

Comment: @tofro : What he has illustrated is a "ping-pong" buffer rather than a ring buffer, and not that uncommon.  Often used for DMA buffering and block sampling in signal processing.  We don't know the application so while a ring buffer is a valid suggestion, it may not match the access pattern.  The pseudocode suggests perhaps the access pattern is random access rather than sequential access.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 3 arrays. One that is being written. One that is ready for reading. One that is actually being read. When the reader has consumed its array, it swaps its array for the one that is ready for reading. When the writer has filled an array, it swaps its array for the one that is ready for reading.

```
int arrayA[128];
int arrayB[128];
int arrayC[128];

int *writePointer = arrayA;
int *readPointer = arrayB;
int *readReady = arrayC;

/* producer */
void on_interrupt () {
    int is_full = fill(writePointer);
    if (is_full) {
        swap(writePointer, readReady);
        ready_to_read_set(true);
        activate_reader();
    }
}

/* consumer */
void reader () {
    swap(readPointer, readReady);
    ready_to_read_set(false);
    drain(readPointer);
}
```

This assumes that if a filled array in ready for reading has not been read yet, there is no problem with swapping it out with a newly filled array.

Your sample doesn't show how the reader waits for input, but whatever mechanism is present can be adapted with this approach at the point the writer swaps in an array that is ready for reading.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest five patterns (at least) that might suit depending on how you need to access the data, and the data rate.

- **Disable the interrupt during a read operation** - simple brute force. Minimal changes to your existing code.  Risks loosing data if the read access is too long.
- **Spin-lock data consistency** - read the data from the current read buffer and after, check that the read buffer has not been switched - if it has, read again until the read buffer at the start is the same as that at the end.
- **Spin-lock synchronisation** - poll a flag that is set at the buffer switch, and read the data at than after time rather than an asynchronous delay.
- If the data is also *read* sequentially **use a ring buffer**.
- Deploy a preemptive scheduling kernel and **block on a semaphore** that is given by the interrupt when the buffer is ready.  This is similar to the spin-lock synchronisation option but gives you the opportunity to do useful work in other threads while waiting for the data.  In fact the availability of a scheduler (typically an RTOS) provides opportunities for other solutions such as a message queue, but is perhaps a somewhat heavyweight solution in this case.

You can also simplify the interrupt by using a single buffer that is twice the size, and simply assign the read/write pointers to the start and middle of that buffer.  The interrupt can be further optimised by exploiting the length being a power of two.

### **Example Spin-lock data consistency:**

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BUFFER_LEN (1u<<8) // Ensure a power of two 
#define BUFFER_MODULO_MASK (BUFFER_LEN - 1u)
volatile int buffer_array[256];
volatile int* buffer[2] = { &buffer_array[0], &buffer_array[BUFFER_LEN / 2] ;

typedef uint8_t atomic_int_t ;  // Use a type for which read/write is uninterruptable on your target
volatile atomic_int_t read_buffer_select = 1 ;

int main()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        bool data_read = false ;
        atomic_int_t current_buffer_select = read_buffer_select ;
        do
        {
            // Read operation attempt
            readfrom( buffer[current_buffer_select] ) ; 

            if( current_buffer_select == read_buffer_select )
            {
                // Read buffer consistent during read - comeplete
                data_read = true ;
            }
            else
            {
                // Read bufer changed during read - try again
                current_buffer_select = read_buffer_select   
            }

        } while( !data_read ) ;

        delay(100);
    }
}

_interrupt rx() 
{
    static int index = 0;
    buffer_array[index] = readVal();
    index++ ;
    index &= BUFFER_MODULO_MASK ;
    if( index == 0 || index == BUFFER_LEN / 2 )
    { 
        read_buffer_select == 0 ? 1 : 0 ;
    }
}
```

### **Example spin-lock synchronisation**

As above except for the main loop:

```
    for(;;)
    {
        // Synchronise to buffer completion
        atomic_int_t current_buffer_select = read_buffer_select ;
        while( current_buffer_select == read_buffer_select )
        {
            // do nothing
        }

        // Optimum time to read data
        readfrom( buffer[read_buffer_select] ) ; 
    }
```

Here instead of having an asynchronous delay, the loop waits until the interrupt switched buffers giving you the maximum amount of time possible to read and process the data.

The synchronised method has less potential for data loss - if data loss is an issue, the data-consistency method relies on the delay length being small enough to avoid data loss but long enough to avoid reading the same data twice.  Unless data loss is not an issue, the synchronised method should be preferred.

You can of course combine the two; synchronise the read and then check the read/processing did not take longer than the buffering.  That is perhaps unnecessary - the buffer length should be selected to avoid that.

The other two methods are perhaps more complex in implementation (but more flexible) and it is not clear that they are relevant in this case, so I have not provided an example.